# Что возвращает при программировании под Android конструкция fragment.toString()

Tags: android, android-fragment

Собственно есть фрагмент, в котором я вставил лог

```
Log.d(TAG, mDetailsBasketFragments.toString());
```

При первом запуске он выдает такую инфу:
    ***DetailsBasketFragment{26a88edb} ***
потом когда я загружаю через replace второй фрагмент и затем жму кнопку back я уже получаю вот такою инфу
    ***DetailsBasketFragment{26a88edb #1 id=0x7f0d0091}***

Фрагмент у меня заново не создается!

Comment: В таких случаях лучше изучить класс `Fragment` а именно его переопределенный метод `toString()`

Comment: @Flippy все гениальное просто :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
    DebugUtils.buildShortClassTag(this, sb);
    if (mIndex >= 0) {
        sb.append(" #");
        sb.append(mIndex);
    }
    if (mFragmentId != 0) {
        sb.append(" id=0x");
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(mFragmentId));
    }
    if (mTag != null) {
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(mTag);
    }
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
```

> Возвращает строку из Имени и индекса активного стека фрагментов  + id фрагмента в очереди
>   + тег фрагмента.